# SAPUI5 TableSelectDialog Search Value

Tags: sapui5

I'm using TableSelectDialog control where I'm also performing some search. In order to get the search value on livesearch, i'm using **oControlEvent.getParameters.value** but it returns me undefined as I see it in an alert box.

Any idea why it is giving me undefined or any other way I can get the value I typed in search field.

Answer (score 1):

This works with `oEvent.getParameters().value`.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, as most used way to find the query value is for a SeachField, we use

`oEvent.getSource().getValue`

Here, you can also find the query string similarly:

> `oEvent.getSource()._oSearchField.getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers here you can also do:

```
onSearch: function(oControlEvent) {
    oControlEvent.getParameters("value");
}
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TableSelectDialog/events/search